# Heroku/Django/Zennia installation. Now what?

Tags: django, heroku, blogs

I recently implemented a copy of the django-blog zinnia via django on Heroku. Here is the link of the site now running. http://warm-snow-8555.herokuapp.com

I created this by following three different tutorials in tandem, [Django's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/intro/tutorial01/), [Zennia's](http://django-blog-zinnia.com/documentation/getting-started/install/#urls), and [Heroku's](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django). I want to change the weblog from the default look to my own, but I'm uncertain about how exactly should I accomplish that.

1. Is there a general best-practices for implementing your own version of someone else's django app?

Currently, my urls.py does this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', include('zinnia.urls')),
url(r'^weblog/', include('zinnia.urls')),
url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

...it works, but zinnia is in the venv folder (created by virtualenv) and any changes I make to those file will not persist to the heroku version online.

1. Should I just copy everything that is in the `\venv\Lib\site-packages\zinnia` directory and get rid of the url refences to the zinni directory altogether?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is really a lot behind this question. This involved not only database persistent, but a variety of other factors.

Instead of answering this question, I'd just like to link you to the official Django docs. What I'd do is go through the [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/) on your own, and make sure you understand how it works.

What is likely your issue is that you haven't setup and/or configured your database.